# How do I write a Regular Expression to find a string of any length, consisting of only 3 all different digits?

Tags: regex

How do I write a Regular Expression to find a string of any length, consisting of only 3 all different digits?

eg 3213213312, 679976679, and does not correspond 56785678

Comment: I'm not sure that regex is the best way to do that. Simple check in application  would be easier

Comment: No doubt someone will be able to come up with something really clever but regex is not the right tool for this job.

Comment: which language/tool are you using

Comment: Are these digits known before hand, or does it just need to make sure only 3 characters are used?

Answer (score 4):

I agree that regex isn't the right tool for this, but it's possible:

```
^(\d)\1*(?!\1)(\d)(?:\1|\2)*(?!\1|\2)(\d)(?:\1||\2|\3)*$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                 # Start of string
(\d)              # Match the first digit
\1*               # possibly more than once
(?!\1)            # Now match (as long as it's not the same one)
(\d)              # another digit
(?:\1|\2)*        # and possibly more repetitions of the first two.
(?!\1|\2)         # Then match (as long as it's one like before)
(\d)              # a third digit.
(?:\1||\2|\3)*    # Now match any number of one of the three digits
$                 # until the end of the string.
```

A better solution, for example in Python:

```
def threedigits(string):
    return string.isdigit() and len(set(string))==3
```

That's much more readable (and most certainly faster).

```
>>> threedigits("234")
True
>>> threedigits("234234")
True
>>> threedigits("2342345")
False
>>> threedigits("23232323")
False
```

Answer (score 3):

Regex (if you must): [**Tim Pietzcker**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19248701/763371)

Better approach (PHP):

```
$letters = count(array_unique(str_split("21323132")));//3
```

Better approach (JavaScript):

```
var ltrs = '32132121232'.split('');
var unique=[];
for(var i=0,c=ltrs.length;i<c;i++)
{
    if(unique.indexOf(ltrs[i])==-1)
    {
        unique.push(ltrs[i]);
    }
}
console.log(unique.length);//3
```

By better, I must point out that I am taking into account flexibility, legibility and ability to modify at a later date. No performance tests or standards have been accounted for.

Ended up making a generic JavaScript solution:

```
function isxnums(str,x)
{
    x = x || 3;//Default number check to 3
    if(str.match(/^[0-9]+$/)==null) return false;
    for(var c=0,s2='';str!='';)
    {
        var num = str.match(/^([0-9])/)[1];
        s2 = str.replace(new RegExp(num,'g'),'');
        if(str != s2) c++;
        str = s2;
    }
    return c==x;
}

isxnums('123');//true
isxnums('3213213312');//true
isxnums('11111');//false
isxnums('11111',1);//true
```

Comment: That's not quite right. `1212123` fails.

Comment: I didn't test, but would this match `11111111` too?

Comment: @TimPietzcker So it doesn't - fixed.

Comment: @Kent Yup, Tim's posted a working one, so I've removed mine and pointed users at his.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which language are you using, but this way may help:

- take the 1st char (number) of the string
- replace the char in whole string with empty

do the above step 3 times,

- if it cannot be done in 3 times, return false
- after that if the input string is still not empty, return false.
- otherwise True